# jgoodies binding several jtoggle button

Tags: swing, jgoodies, jtogglebutton

I would like to bind 3 toggle button with my domain object.  The 3 toggle should be mutually exclusive, if one of the 3 boolean property in my domain object is true, then the toggle corresponding is selected and the other 2 are unselected.

I have a solution based on RadioButtonAdapter, but i find it strange. So I was wondering if there was another solution...

Comment: what have you tried so far and what exactly is the problem? AFAIR, goodies comes with example code which demonstrates how to reach your goal

Comment: I haven't found the exemple code in the .zip (version 2.5) i downloaded but i could find some basic exemple on the web.  So i have a solution for my problem that use RadioButtonAdapter.  I was just wondering if there was another way of doing it.

Comment: what's wrong with the solution you found?

Comment: It's not using booleans that i have in my model, but an enum value, that contains the three state, one for each button. I thought that there was solution based on booleans...Using RadioButtonAdapter seems to be a turn around.  And i want to use JGoodies the way it has to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your radio-buttons in a [ButtonGroup](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html). Then bind your buttons as usual with `Bindings.bind`.